# Need to write a query in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
select cashiername 
from payment 
where CashierID = 007
```

I want to write a query when `cashierid = 007`, `cashiername` would be N/A and other `cashiername` appear according to their `cashierid`

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result. (As formatted text, not images.)

Comment: Your question is not clear, see if you can re-word it before someone flags it.

Comment: Is CashierID a number or a string? The leading 0s indicate it may be a string. If it is a number then 007 is the same as 7.

Comment: @MarkSinkinson it wouldn't FAIL through necessarily if it were an int `field` so it's better to leave him to is preferred nomenclature surely

Answer (score 3):

```
select CASE WHEN CashierID = '007' THEN 'N/A' ELSE cashiername END as cashiername   
from payment
```

Comment: I can't decipher gobbledygook as well as you can!

Comment: Not sure why this got a downvote. It is unclear if the OP needs '007' as a string or an int. They posted it as an int in their query.

Comment: @SeanLange, ty, for the data type, I added `'` for solving the conflicts xD

Answer (score 0):

```
 select cashiername from payment where CashierID = 007
```

does this:

it is a query that returns the rows where cashierid = 007. The cashiername is N/A.

To retrieve other cashiernames according to their cashierid you would simply write

```
select cashiername, CashierID  from payment
```

Comment: seems that literally re-writing the question in exposition form, taking out the grammar issues, and literally replacing questions with examples word-byword gets you a down vote these days